# How to ping people/roles inside a Discord Embed?

Tags: python, discord.py, embed

So I've looked around and although there are a bunch of similarly phrased questions but I haven't found one that addresses my question. I don't really want to trawl through Stack Overflow, so here's to hoping this isn't a duplicate.

So I coded a Discord Embed that requires pinging to work. The text is displaying as a discord ping should look with the light blue background and such, but there is no ping and users simply get a new message notification instead of a ping. This is the case for role mentions as well as user mentions. For user mentions I used `author.mention` and for role mentions I used the ID. Does anyone know how I can change this "setting?"

One possible workaround that I have thought up is that I could ping the needed parties and then instantly delete the ping right before sending the embed, but for my peace of mind I would prefer if the ping was the one which is displayed in the embed.

Comment: in discord, you can ping someone in an embed, but they won't get the notifications because that's how discord works

Answer (score 4):

As yotam rec said in the comment, it is impossible to have the user be pinged from the embed alone. Sending and deleting a ping can annoy the user because they can't see where the ping came from.

So I came up with alternatives:
Mention 2 times, one in the message and one in embed.

[image: Ping 2 times, one in message and one in embed]

You can do this by just adding `embed=embed` after any message.

```py
await ctx.send(ctx.message.author.mention, embed=embed)
```

Alternatively, you can reply to the user with ping on, but from your question, it looks like you need to ping multiple people so this would not work.

[image: Reply with ping on]

Here is the code:

```py
await ctx.reply(mention_author=True, embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 2):

So as i know you can`t do a "Ping" in a Embed at least not what you call a ping. To ping People you have to do a ping in a normal message. You could do this before the embed and delete it or you could not delete it.